# colors in tablecells in LaTeX

Tags: tables, color

I'm making a tabular and I want some of the cells to be colored. So I searched how to make colored cells. I now have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\definecolor{lblue}{RGB}{218,227,254}
\newcommand{\lblue}{\cellcolor{teal}}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\lblue yes & no \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

The problem is, I want to use two different colors, so I thought I can define a new color, just like I did before:

```
\definecolor{newcolor}{RGB}{200,100,50}
\newcommand{\newcolor}{\cellcolor{teal}}
```

But everything turns into the first defined color. Even if I try `{rgb}` instead of `{RGB}`.
My question is: why can't I make two (or multiple) different colors? How should I make the two colors? Should I use different type of `\newcommand`?
Hopefully somebody can help me.

Answer (score 6):

Please always make your examples complete documents, you are missing a document environment.

You just need to use `newcolor` as the colour.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\definecolor{lblue}{RGB}{218,227,254}
\newcommand{\lblue}{\cellcolor{teal}}
\definecolor{newcolor}{RGB}{200,100,50}
\newcommand{\newcolor}{\cellcolor{newcolor}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\lblue yes &\newcolor no \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```